# Web server failing to start on Docker-Symfony project

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, nginx, docker-compose

I am getting myself accustomed to Docker-compose and I decided to set-up an environment for PHP/SQL/WEB, using Symfony-framework. I found this [web-site](https://medium.com/@mkt_43322/how-to-setup-docker-for-a-symfony-project-26d304359592) to guide me on how to do it. Well, I somewhat did it, but I have encountered some hiccups:

- I had to modify the docker-compose.yml file and set the web server ports inside "" instead of '' (as far as I researched)
- The MySQL server fails to start (see log below)

Console log:

```
The MYSQL_DATABASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The MYSQL_ROOT_HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Starting project_db_1 ... done
Starting project_php_1 ... done
Starting project_web_1 ... done
Attaching to project_db_1, project_php_1, project_web_1
db_1   | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.15-1.1.10
db_1   | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.15-1.1.10
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:34.408593Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 1
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:35.798218Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:35.811751Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:35.811764Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:35.812340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db_1   | 2019-02-12T16:56:37.319368Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
project_db_1 exited with code 1
```

The docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: build/php
    expose:
      - '9000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/symfony:cached
      - ./logs:/var/log
  web:
    build: build/nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "81:80"
    depends_on:
        - php
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/symfony:cached
        - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=${MYSQL_ROOT_HOST}
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

The directory/file tree is as follows:

```
├───build
│   ├───nginx
│   │   └───sites-enabled
│   └───php
│       └───conf
├───logs
├───mysql
│   ├───#innodb_temp
│   ├───mysql
│   ├───performance_schema
│   └───sys
└───symfony
```

The .conf files can be found at:

- [nginx.conf](https://pastebin.com/HbJ4GdsT)
- [default_symfony](https://pastebin.com/eQjjCJb5)
- [php-fpm.conf](https://pastebin.com/2kKXVWSu)
- [www.conf](https://pastebin.com/zaWzJvDx)

Comment: Have you tried using the official mysql-image, `image: mysql:latest`, instead?

Comment: That did not work for me. It also failed to pull it due to some credential issue, although docker login succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one. 
https://github.com/coloso/symfony-docker 
pretty much the same and works here really well (you need to quit the first command manually "docker-compose up --build" but everything is fine). There are also many docker problems with mysql higher than 5.7. So just use 5.7. Best Regards

Comment: I will give that a look, when I get home. Doing things manually doesn't seem to be reliable all the time. Best regards.